# Convert PyTorch tensor to python list

Tags: python, pytorch

How do I convert a PyTorch `Tensor` into a python `list`?

I want to convert a tensor of size `[1, 2048, 1, 1]` into a list of 2048 elements. My tensor has floating point values. Is there a solution which also works with other data types such as int?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Use [`Tensor.tolist()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.tolist) e.g:

> ```
> >>> import torch
> >>> a = torch.randn(2, 2)
> >>> a.tolist()
> [[0.012766935862600803, 0.5415473580360413],
>  [-0.08909505605697632, 0.7729271650314331]]
> >>> a[0,0].tolist()
> 0.012766935862600803
> ```

To remove all dimensions of size `1`, use `a.squeeze().tolist()`.

Alternatively, if all but one dimension are of size `1` (or you wish to get a list of every element of the tensor) you may use [`a.flatten().tolist()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.flatten).

Answer (score 14):

Tensor to list:

```
a_list  = embeddings.tolist()
```

list to Tensor:

```
a_tensor = torch.Tensor(a_list).cuda()
```

Answer (score 2):

**#@pyorch** tensor to list or strings

```
in[]
#bbox predictions
boxes = predictions[:, :4]
print(boxes)

out[]

tensor(54.97658) tensor(393.99637) tensor(225.55316) tensor(879.53503)
tensor(670.91669) tensor(400.35202) tensor(810.) tensor(878.34045)
tensor(219.87546) tensor(408.02075) tensor(346.14133) tensor(860.66687)
tensor(13.24882) tensor(217.30855) tensor(800.23413) tensor(737.75751)
tensor(0.12453) tensor(552.29401) tensor(76.41209) tensor(885.35455)
tensor(656.11823) tensor(625.61261) tensor(689.63586) tensor(713.37250)
```

after

```
in[]

boxes = boxes.tolist()
print(boxes)
    
out []
    
54.97657775878906 393.9963684082031 225.55316162109375 879.5350341796875
670.9166870117188 400.3520202636719 810.0 878.3404541015625
219.87545776367188 408.020751953125 346.1413269042969 860.6668701171875
13.24881649017334 217.3085479736328 800.234130859375 737.7575073242188
0.12453281879425049 552.2940063476562 76.4120864868164 885.3545532226562
656.1182250976562 625.6126098632812 689.6358642578125 713.3724975585938
```