# Transform flair language model tensors for viewing in TensorBoard Projector

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensorboard, flair

I want to convert "vectors,"

```
vectors = [token.embedding for token in sentence]
print(type(vectors))
<class 'list'>

print(vectors)
[tensor([ 0.0077, -0.0227, -0.0004,  ...,  0.1377, -0.0003,  0.0028]),
...
tensor([ 0.0003, -0.0461,  0.0043,  ..., -0.0126, -0.0004,  0.0142])]
```

to

```
0.0077 -0.0227 -0.0004 ... 0.1377 -0.0003 0.0028
...
0.0003 -0.0461 0.0043 ... -0.0126 -0.0004 0.0142
```

and write that to a TSV.

Aside: those embeddings are from `flair` (https://github.com/zalandoresearch/flair): how can I get the full output, not the `-0.0004 ... 0.1377` abbreviated output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I dug around ...

1. It turns out those are PyTorch tensors (Flair uses PyTorch).  For a simple conversion to NumPy arrays (per the PyTorch docs at https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.tolist and [this StackOverFlow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53903373/convert-pytorch-tensor-to-python-list) use `tolist()`, a PyTorch method.

   ```
   >>> import torch
   >>> a = torch.randn(2, 2)
   >>> print(a)
   tensor([[-2.1693,  0.7698],
           [ 0.0497,  0.8462]])

   >>> a.tolist()
   [[-2.1692984104156494, 0.7698001265525818],
    [0.049718063324689865, 0.8462421298027039]]
   ```

---

2. Per my original question, here's how to convert those data to plain text and write them to TSV files.

   ```
   from flair.embeddings import FlairEmbeddings, Sentence
   from flair.models import SequenceTagger
   from flair.embeddings import StackedEmbeddings

   embeddings_f = FlairEmbeddings('pubmed-forward')
   embeddings_b = FlairEmbeddings('pubmed-backward')

   sentence = Sentence('The RAS-MAPK signalling cascade serves as a central node in transducing signals from membrane receptors to the nucleus.')

   tagger = SequenceTagger.load('ner')

   tagger.predict(sentence)
   embeddings_f.embed(sentence)

   stacked_embeddings = StackedEmbeddings([
       embeddings_f,
       embeddings_b,
   ])

   stacked_embeddings.embed(sentence)

   # for token in sentence:
   #     print(token)
   #     print(token.embedding)
   #     print(token.embedding.shape)

   tokens = [token for token in sentence]
   print(tokens)
   '''
     [Token: 1 The, Token: 2 RAS-MAPK, Token: 3 signalling, Token: 4 cascade, Token: 5 serves, Token: 6 as, Token: 7 a, Token: 8 central, Token: 9 node, Token: 10 in, Token: 11 transducing, Token: 12 signals, Token: 13 from, Token: 14 membrane, Token: 15 receptors, Token: 16 to, Token: 17 the, Token: 18 nucleus.]
   '''

   ## https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-split/

   tokens = [str(token).split()[2] for token in sentence]
   print(tokens)
   '''
     ['The', 'RAS-MAPK', 'signalling', 'cascade', 'serves', 'as', 'a', 'central', 'node', 'in', 'transducing', 'signals', 'from', 'membrane', 'receptors', 'to', 'the', 'nucleus.']
   '''

   tensors = [token.embedding for token in sentence]
   print(tensors)
   '''
     [tensor([ 0.0077, -0.0227, -0.0004,  ...,  0.1377, -0.0003,  0.0028]),
     tensor([-0.0007, -0.1601, -0.0274,  ...,  0.1982,  0.0013,  0.0042]),
     tensor([ 4.2534e-03, -3.1018e-01, -3.9660e-01,  ...,  5.9336e-02, -9.4445e-05,  1.0025e-02]),
     tensor([ 0.0026, -0.0087, -0.1398,  ..., -0.0037,  0.0012,  0.0274]),
     tensor([-0.0005, -0.0164, -0.0233,  ..., -0.0013,  0.0039,  0.0004]),
     tensor([ 3.8261e-03, -7.6409e-02, -1.8632e-02,  ..., -2.8906e-03, -4.4556e-04,  5.6909e-05]),
     tensor([ 0.0035, -0.0207,  0.1700,  ..., -0.0193,  0.0017,  0.0006]),
     tensor([ 0.0159, -0.4097, -0.0489,  ...,  0.0743,  0.0005,  0.0012]),
     tensor([ 9.7725e-03, -3.3817e-01, -2.2848e-02,  ..., -6.6284e-02, 2.3646e-04,  1.0505e-02]),
     tensor([ 0.0219, -0.0677, -0.0154,  ...,  0.0102,  0.0066,  0.0016]),
     tensor([ 0.0092, -0.0431, -0.0450,  ...,  0.0060,  0.0002,  0.0005]),
     tensor([ 0.0047, -0.2732, -0.0408,  ...,  0.0136,  0.0005,  0.0072]),
     tensor([ 0.0072, -0.0173, -0.0149,  ..., -0.0013, -0.0004,  0.0056]),
     tensor([ 0.0086, -0.1151, -0.0629,  ...,  0.0043,  0.0050,  0.0016]),
     tensor([ 7.6452e-03, -2.3825e-01, -1.5683e-02,  ..., -5.4974e-04, -1.4646e-04,  6.6120e-03]),
     tensor([ 0.0038, -0.0354, -0.1337,  ...,  0.0060, -0.0004,  0.0102]),
     tensor([ 0.0186, -0.0151, -0.0641,  ...,  0.0188,  0.0391,  0.0069]),
     tensor([ 0.0003, -0.0461,  0.0043,  ..., -0.0126, -0.0004,  0.0142])]
   '''

   # ----------------------------------------
   ## Write those data to TSV files.

   ## https://stackoverflow.com/a/29896136/1904943

   import csv

   metadata_f = 'metadata.tsv'
   tensors_f = 'tensors.tsv'

   with open(metadata_f, 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as tsv_file:
       tsv_writer = csv.writer(tsv_file, delimiter='\t', lineterminator='\n')
       for token in tokens:
           ## Assign to a dummy variable ( _ ) to suppress character counts;
           ## if I use (token), rather than ([token]), I get spaces between all characters:
           _ = tsv_writer.writerow([token])

   ## metadata.tsv :
   '''
     The
     RAS-MAPK
     signalling
     cascade
     serves
     as
     a
     central
     node
     in
     transducing
     signals
     from
     membrane
     receptors
     to
     the
     nucleus.
   '''

   with open(metadata_f, 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as tsv_file:
       tsv_writer = csv.writer(tsv_file, delimiter='\t', lineterminator='\n')
       _ = tsv_writer.writerow(tokens)

   ## metadata.tsv :
   '''
     The   RAS-MAPK    signalling  cascade serves  as  a   central node    in  transducing signals from    membrane    receptors   to  the nucleus.
   '''

   tensors = [token.embedding for token in sentence]
   print(tensors)
   '''
     [tensor([ 0.0077, -0.0227, -0.0004,  ...,  0.1377, -0.0003,  0.0028]),
     tensor([-0.0007, -0.1601, -0.0274,  ...,  0.1982,  0.0013,  0.0042]),
     tensor([ 4.2534e-03, -3.1018e-01, -3.9660e-01,  ...,  5.9336e-02, -9.4445e-05,  1.0025e-02]),
     tensor([ 0.0026, -0.0087, -0.1398,  ..., -0.0037,  0.0012,  0.0274]),
     tensor([-0.0005, -0.0164, -0.0233,  ..., -0.0013,  0.0039,  0.0004]),
     tensor([ 3.8261e-03, -7.6409e-02, -1.8632e-02,  ..., -2.8906e-03, -4.4556e-04,  5.6909e-05]),
     tensor([ 0.0035, -0.0207,  0.1700,  ..., -0.0193,  0.0017,  0.0006]),
     tensor([ 0.0159, -0.4097, -0.0489,  ...,  0.0743,  0.0005,  0.0012]),
     tensor([ 9.7725e-03, -3.3817e-01, -2.2848e-02,  ..., -6.6284e-02, 2.3646e-04,  1.0505e-02]),
     tensor([ 0.0219, -0.0677, -0.0154,  ...,  0.0102,  0.0066,  0.0016]),
     tensor([ 0.0092, -0.0431, -0.0450,  ...,  0.0060,  0.0002,  0.0005]),
     tensor([ 0.0047, -0.2732, -0.0408,  ...,  0.0136,  0.0005,  0.0072]),
     tensor([ 0.0072, -0.0173, -0.0149,  ..., -0.0013, -0.0004,  0.0056]),
     tensor([ 0.0086, -0.1151, -0.0629,  ...,  0.0043,  0.0050,  0.0016]),
     tensor([ 7.6452e-03, -2.3825e-01, -1.5683e-02,  ..., -5.4974e-04, -1.4646e-04,  6.6120e-03]),
     tensor([ 0.0038, -0.0354, -0.1337,  ...,  0.0060, -0.0004,  0.0102]),
     tensor([ 0.0186, -0.0151, -0.0641,  ...,  0.0188,  0.0391,  0.0069]),
     tensor([ 0.0003, -0.0461,  0.0043,  ..., -0.0126, -0.0004,  0.0142])]
   '''

   with open(tensors_f, 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as tsv_file:
       tsv_writer = csv.writer(tsv_file, delimiter='\t', lineterminator='\n')
       for token in sentence:
           embedding = token.embedding
           _ = tsv_writer.writerow(embedding.tolist())

   ## tensors.tsv (18 lines: one embedding per token in metadata.tsv):
   ## note: enormous output, even for this simple sentence.
   '''
     0.007691788021475077  -0.02268664352595806    -0.0004340760060586035  ...
   '''
   ```

---

3. Last, my intention for all of that was to load contextual language embeddings (Flair, etc.) into TensorFlow's [Embedding Projector](https://projector.tensorflow.org/).  It turns out all I needed to to was to convert (here, Flair data) to NumPy arrays, and load them into a TensorFlow TensorBoard instance (no need for TSV files!).

   I describe that in detail in my blog post, here: [Visualizing Language Model Tensors (Embeddings) in TensorFlow's TensorBoard [TensorBoard Projector: PCA; t-SNE; ...]](https://persagen.com/2019/11/28/tensorboard_projector.html).

Answer (score 0):

For getting the tokens you can use the token.text and token.embedding.tolist() to get the embeddings:

```
def flair_embeddings(sentences, output_file=None):
    if output_file:
        f = open(output_file, 'w')
    # init embedding
    flair_embedding_forward = FlairEmbeddings('news-forward')
    
    for i, sent in enumerate(sentences):
        print("Encoding the {}th input sentence!".format(i))
        # create a sentence
        sentence = Sentence(sent)

        # embed words in sentence
        flair_embedding_forward.embed(sentence)

        for token in sentence:
            if output_file:

                f.write(token.text + "\t" + "\t".join([str(num) for num in token.embedding.tolist()]) + '\n')
            else:
                print(token.text + "\t" + "\t".join([str(num) for num in token.embedding.tolist()]) + '\n')
```